# Proper 100% IsOnline implementation for asp.net membership

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, membership

I have to design a CMS where a set of credentials can only be used once. So if a user has logged in from his computer, no-one can login with his credentials from another location until that user logs out.

Now using the asp.net membership provider out the box, the IsOnline method returns a boolean that reflects the timeout window vs. the last activity date. This is not a viable option for me, because if the user just closes the browser after logging in, IsOnline will still be true. But his session will be destroyed(assuming he's not using Remember Me) so if he tries to log in somewhere else it will say "Sorry you still logged in".

Are there any hard and fast options for doing this..?

I was thinking of forcing the users to be "Remembered" so when he logs in a boolean "IsReallyOnline" will be set to true and vice versa when he logs out.. Although this option has it's limitations, (people turn off cookies, not logging out and closing the browser then sum1 else comes and browser to the site and he's logged in etc....) it seems like the most viable for now?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really asking for something that is outside of the remit of the web. The HTTP protocol is by definition stateless, meaning that at any one time; a server never need know if a client still exists. The newer/older implementations of web server programming languages (e.g. php / asp.net mvc) for the most part shy away from storing any state about connected/active clients.

**Some things to ask yourself include:**

How long may a user be 'active' on a page without causing a postback? Javascript based pages may allow for a user to interactively be using a page for quite some time before any kind of postback happens.

Will the users be going through a proxy or caching server? Multiple requests from 'different' users may come from the same machine in this case.

Will your application be running on one machine only, or maybe a server farm? You'll need to ensure that load balancing (for example) doesn't punt different users onto different servers allowing multiple logins.

How about a user legitimately using two different browsers on the same machine? Is this to be allowed?

One might suggest your problem here stems from trying to use the wrong technology given your requirements? Maybe writing a client application which uses direct connection to your servers would be more 'secure'? (Yes I understand this is huge hassles but if your one user / one logon requirement is absolute maybe you could explore this avenue?)

**Oh alright, a web solution**

For a http centric solution you could try a javascript timer making a request to your server every X seconds to indicate that the session is still active. As long as the browser is open and the network connection valid you should be getting these 'pings'. The session is kept open by the cookie passed by the httprequest.

You'll be able to code the 'ping' page to store the user details into either the application object or some membership provider of your choice then interrogate this provider whenever a client attempts to log in.

This will require a relatively short time-out on a session or some other mechanism to ensure that a crashed browser doesn't lock your legitimate user out for too long.

Please note: This will fail horribly if the user doesn't have javascript turned on (Don't assume that they will have!)

Answer (score 1):

Fast Option: Store IsOnline as a session.
Check if session is true, then allow. If not, don't allow.

If user closes browser, he will be logged outas its in a session.